# Orbeon: dynamically add item to select object

Tags: xpath, orbeon, xforms

I would like to add the items to select object based on value of another fields. For example, if my related field have value "1", i would like to have only one item into select object.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you include some example code?

Comment: I post my solution, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem using orbeon "Database service", i'll try to explain it step by step.

1° i have added a "database services" that create temporary table into database (in my case database server is **oracle**) with this sql code:

```
with t as 
(
  select (i.column_value).getnumberval() Codes  from        xmltable('1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20') i
)
SELECT Codes as id, CONCAT(Codes, '° select') as value FROM t
WHERE Codes &lt; (<sql:param type="xs:string" select="''"/> +1)
```

This query creates a list of items with "id" and "value". To see the output of the query run it into one oracle client.

2° i have added  an "Actions" where i  set into the field "Service to call" my database service, into the field "Set Database service parameter" my input field that contain number used by my query and into the field "Destination selection control" the destination dropdown menu.

For more details on how to configure dropdown menu follow this link http://discuss.orbeon.com/Prepopulating-the-dropdown-with-database-service-is-not-working-td4656948.html where there is the screen shot.